# Stylesheet element works in Windows but not raspberry-pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyside2, qtstylesheets

I'm writing a program on a Windows 10 machine and SSHing the code into the machine it will be running on - a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. When applying some stylesheets to certain objects they look great on Windows, but certain elements aren't getting picked up on the Linux machine.

I've created a test program to show what is happening:

[image: This is on the Windows machine, all is working as expected]

[image: This is on the Raspbian machine]

The only problem i'm having on the Raspbian machine is that the background isn't getting filled. The font size and color attributes are getting picked up fine. I've tried using `.autoFillBackground()` and `.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground)` but neither yielded any results.

I've also tried a combination of `QPushButton::active:` and `background:`/`background-color:` without any luck.

Any ideas?

EDIT: PySide2 was installed using:

`apt-get install python3-pyside2.qt3dcore python3-pyside2.qt3dinput python3-pyside2.qt3dlogic python3-pyside2.qt3drender python3-pyside2.qtcharts python3-pyside2.qtconcurrent python3-pyside2.qtcore python3-pyside2.qtgui python3-pyside2.qthelp python3-pyside2.qtlocation python3-pyside2.qtmultimedia python3-pyside2.qtmultimediawidgets python3-pyside2.qtnetwork python3-pyside2.qtopengl python3-pyside2.qtpositioning python3-pyside2.qtprintsupport python3-pyside2.qtqml python3-pyside2.qtquick python3-pyside2.qtquickwidgets python3-pyside2.qtscript python3-pyside2.qtscripttools python3-pyside2.qtsensors python3-pyside2.qtsql python3-pyside2.qtsvg python3-pyside2.qttest python3-pyside2.qttexttospeech python3-pyside2.qtuitools python3-pyside2.qtwebchannel python3-pyside2.qtwebsockets python3-pyside2.qtwidgets python3-pyside2.qtx11extras python3-pyside2.qtxml python3-pyside2.qtxmlpatterns python3-pyside2uic`

from https://forum.qt.io/topic/112813/installing-pyside2-on-raspberry-pi

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Button 2")

        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("""background: blue; color: yellow; border: 3px solid black""")
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("background: red; color: white; font-size: 30px;")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn2)

        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: In linux it works correctly (linux arch with KDE) with PySide2 5.14.2 and Python 3.8.2: https://i.imgur.com/lPQx2B4.png . I recommend you run it from the console so you can see if there are any errors

Comment: Thats strange, it must just be something to do with Raspbian then. Its odd that the first button correctly displays the background color, but btn2 doesn't. Any idea what could be causing this?
I had some trouble installing Pyside2 on the RPi as its using arm7h architechture, which is apparently something PySide2 doesn't like. It could be missing some key files?

Comment: Analyze if a library is missing. Why don't you use PyQt5?

Comment: I had similar problems installing PyQt5 on the RPi, but managed to find a very long pip installer for PySide2. I'm also using it in a commercial setting, and as far as i'm aware you need to buy a commercial license for PyQt5. 

I'm not sure what i'm looking for to be honest library-wise, i know that QIcons work so might just replace the whole button as a QIcon.

Comment: If it is for commercial use then you will have to buy a license either from PyQt5 (Riverbank Computing) or PySide2 (Qt Company) so I see no advantage in one or the other (I have not reviewed the costs). When I used PyQt5 in RPI (years ago) I didn't have those problems, how rare you have problems. I don't know if ssh is causing problems, try VNC.

Comment: SSH is only being used so i can remote desktop in and literally copy and paste the code or .py file in and run from terminal or an editor. I could wipe the RPi and reinstall the OS and PySide2 and pray i guess?

Answer (score 3):

Woo ok, so slight development. I've found that if you add a border the colour will fill. Bit odd but it works i guess. Its not ideal as the button loses its "pressed" state by doing this, but will mess about with it and see where i get.

"border: none;" also fills the background.

[image: Border needed]